# Python error when I try to run one py file

Tags: python, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to run a py file and I got the following error

`IMPORT ERROR : NO MODULE NAMED "BASEHTTPSERVER"`

The code included in py file is the following:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Thanks in advance
Best Regards
Alejandro Castan

Comment: Which version of python do you use?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Python 3.x**
If you're using Python3.x change `from BaseHTTPServer` to `from http.server`.

If you wrote this code for Python 2.x and you are running it with Python3.x, The [2to3](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2Flibrary%2F2to3.html&ei=50grUqbZCcHb0QWgyYCIBw&usg=AFQjCNGRPJXHYMfkDrULR3M3DdRFaW0vQg&sig2=uqL39-GQaCooeI3s6ZBjzg&bvm=bv.51773540,d.d2k) tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

**Answer for Python 2.x**
The error is telling you that `BaseHTTPServer` needs to be in your `PYTHONPATH`.

That is to say, Python cannot find the module `BaseHTTPServer` anywhere, you either need to install it, or if it is installed in a non-standard location, modify your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include it - however this would be a bit of a strange (though not impossible) situation since that module is normally included in Python2.x

Comment: Hi I am using Python 3x. on the other hand I changed the BaseHTTpSever to http.server the code is the following now "import http.server
import ssl
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()"  I got the following error filenotfounerror:[Erno 2] no such file or directory. Thanks for your help

Comment: As falsetru said, specify the correct certfile path and accept my or his answer ;)

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but Could I teach me about how set the correct certfile path? thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746857/how-to-find-the-path-to-a-ssl-cert-file

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.x, try following:

```
import http.server
import ssl

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

[`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html), [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) modules in Python 2 have been merged into [`http.server`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server) module in Python 3.

**UPDATE**

BTW, port number seems wrong. HTTPS port is 443, not 4443.

Comment: Hi first thanks for your help. I ran your code and I got the following filenotfounerror:[Erno 2] no such file or directory

Comment: @AlejandroCastan, Specify the correct certfile path. Try absolute path of it.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but Could I teach me about how try absolute path? thanks

Comment: @AlejandroCastan, Absolute path looks like: `/home/alejandro/path/to/server.pem`

Comment: @AlejandroCastan, Did you create certfile? If you didn't, post another question or search for that.