# SSLError with PRAW?

Tags: python, ssl, praw

I'm trying to get started with PRAW but I'm having issues using login().

I have the following piece of code:

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit('This is a test bot')
r.login('myRedditUsername','password')
```

And I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Is there a way around this outside of disabling SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [praw SSLError during login from shared hosting](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/202):

> It appears that your host doesn't have the proper SSL certificates
>   installed. You can disable using SSL (not recommended) by adding
>
> ```
> r.config._ssl_url = None
> ```
>
> after you create the PRAW object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I looked at that link earlier but it doesn't quite solve my problem as I don't wish to disable SSL. Do you know how I could go about installing the SSL certificates?

Comment: @perlponderer, Q1. Which OS do you use?   Q2. Show me the output of `python -m requests.certs`.

Comment: Using Mac OS X 10.9. Output of python -m requests.certs gave me this:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/cacert.pem

Comment: I no longer receiver the problem when I run my script from the command line. Thanks!

Comment: [According to PRAW's developer](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/934#issuecomment-386114515), the `_ssl_url` option was removed in PRAW 4.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** `_ssl_url` [doesn't work in PRAW 4](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/934#issuecomment-386114515). Use a custom Requests session with `Session.verify`.

## For PRAW 4 or later:

According to [PRAW's developer](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/934#issuecomment-386114515), the option to use `config._ssl_url = None` was removed in PRAW 4. Instead, you can use a custom Requests [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to configure your own SSL settings.

Assuming you are on [a company network with self-signed certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107542/141087), you have two options.

#### Option 1 - Trusting a Self-Signed Certificate

First, export your company's root certificate as a `.pem` file. (See [*Export a PEM-Format Certificate From a Windows System*](https://pubs.vmware.com/flex-1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.horizon.flex.admin.doc%2FGUID-E986742A-17A0-481E-B72A-3CC6340EA7DD.html))

Next, create a Requests session and specify a path directly to your certificate file.

```
import praw
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = '/path/to/certfile.pem'  # Path to cert file
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='###',
                     client_secret='###',
                     user_agent='windows:testapp (by /u/stevoisiak)',
                     requestor_kwargs={'session': session})
```

#### Option 2 - Disabling SSL Verification (insecure)

This method will fully disable HTTPS verification for all requests. While this method is simple, it is **strongly** discouraged for security reasons. (See [*SSL Warnings*](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings))

```
import praw
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False    # Disable SSL
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='###',
                     client_secret='###',
                     user_agent='windows:testapp (by /u/stevoisiak)',
                     requestor_kwargs={'session': session})
```

#### See Also

- GitHub: [SSLError raised while 'r.config._ssl_url = None'](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/934)
- StackOverflow: [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10667960/3357935)
- urllib3: [Advanced Usage - SSL Warnings](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** made the error go away by adding my company's internal certificate to the cacert.pem file.

Below the steps:

1. Find the internal certificate that your browser is using and export
   it as the Base64 encoded format. The details are described here:
   [How to find the path to a SSL cert file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746857/how-to-find-the-path-to-a-ssl-cert-file)
2. Find the cacert.pem file that the request package is using
   (..\Lib\site-packages\request) and copy past at the end of the
   cacert.pem file everything from your internal certificate file.

---

**This is my old answer, I temporary fixed the problem by turning off SSL verification**

I had the same issue on Windows 7, not only with login, but with any request to reddit. `r.config._ssl_url = None` didn't do the trick either, after creating praw.ini as C:\users\&user_name\AppData\Roaming\praw.ini:

```
[reddit]
validate_certs: False
```

I finally made it work. Though I have the InsecureRequestWarning warning. Wanted  to throw that here in case if someone like me is still struggling with that.